# Change column on slicer selection in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Location Table and Target Table

In Location I have City,State and Region

in Target table I have City Target, State Target and Region Target

I have a slicer where I have Region, State and City

If I select all I need avg of Region Targets

If I select any Region I need average of States in the region

and Similar for state selection

and If i select multiple then avarage of selected.

Comment: Can you share a link of the .pbix or .csv ?